# Google colab gives ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement

Tags: python, installation, jupyter-notebook, package, google-colaboratory

I have been using google colab for a few years now and it's the first time that I get a problem of this kind - I am trying to install the package `mpsort` via

```
!pip install mpsort
```

and I get the error message "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mpsort". If it matters, I am installing the package, so that I can use [this github repo](https://github.com/amjsmith/hodpy).

**What should I do to install `mpsort`? Or is there some work-around?** Tnx

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the error. I tried to upgrade pip to version 22.x and another error was raised
I think it has to do with the version of pip maybe? Could you try an older version?

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggestion to download older versions of pip. But pip-tools requires that the pip version is >=20.3. Anyways, even with this older versions (pip==20.3.4 or 21.0) I still get the same error for `mpsort`.

Comment: I was able now to install mpsort with pip 22.2.2
Depends on what you have installed on your system you will need to install some dependencies. First install with pip Cython, numpy. Then sudo apt install libopenmpi-dev, pip install mpi4py and then you should be able to install mpsort. My host system was ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Welcome to the community and thanks for contributing :) I managed with your instructions to install `mpsort`, but now I have the same problem with the package `nbodykit`, I can't install it. If you are willing, can you try the github code I point to in my question and tell me how to install `nbodykit` and other packages, that create problems? Executing it should be easy, but it seems that installing all the packages is a problem. Thanks, if you can do that!